# mysql replication Slave_IO not running

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have problem connecting my slave to master. In past it was working fine and since I restart my master then slave cannot connect.

I checked the slave user on master all good. Everything on slave is the way it suppose to be. But every-time I start the slave my IO Thread is not connecting to master.

Any idea?

Comment: Why would you edit his post like that?

Comment: I corrected tags and made minor grammatical corrections.  What do you take exception to, @KyleBuser?

Comment: Deleted his Thanks and added typo in the title. I understand the tags, but the other stuff, just wondering why even bother ;o

Comment: My edit was primarily for the tags.  mysql tags are well organized and I would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the `Slave_IO_Running` but not the `Slave_SQL_Running`.  In other words, binlogs are updating but queries aren't running.  You can verify this with `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`.

Execute `stop slave;` and then `start slave;` on the slave to restart both IO and SQL.

Otherwise, produce any errors in the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` and the error log, and I will be able to provide further recommendation.

Comment: the issue was the firewall. I could get connected to my master because the firewall was blocking me. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give the print out from both SHOW MASTER STATUS\G and SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G on the respective servers.

Have you checked the logs yet?
Specifically: /var/lib/mysql/[servername].err

I had the same thing happen to me after a restart, what I ended up having to do was reset the replication so that it used a new bin log file.

Comment: the issue was the firewall. I could get connected to my master because the firewall was blocking me. Thanks for your comment.